# Installation is unusably slow, booting from live USB

Tags: 10.10, installation, ubuntu-netbook, live-usb

Here are the screens.  I really need a solution.
I used these instructions http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After about 15 minutes, I see Ubuntu information on the screen, but then it takes another 15-30 minutes to show me the first screen of the installation. It never ends... What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Totty, looks like an IRQ assignment problem, probably with a memory card reader (mmc1) or the card itself.  If you have that hardware, the first thing I would do is unplug the card reader and try again.  If the problem persists, the way to go is to boot with some extra kernel params, such as acpi=noirq, acpi=off, noapic, nolapic, pci=biosirq, irqpoll or pnpbios=off.  It's much of a trial&error thing, but normally acpi=noirq, noapic and nolapic together should do the trick.

A BIOS upgrade helps too...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, (And all I've ever booted from is a USB. Never used a CD/DVD) it normally takes awhile to boot from a USB. **But** on the other hand 15-30 *minutes* is a bit much.

Comment: only to get to the menu. last time a left it to about 5 hours to get to the language selection

Answer (score 0):

I set my bios setting to factory and then check this answer: [My screen is disabled for a long time after I click "Install to harddisk"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24697/my-screen-is-disabled-for-a-long-time-after-i-click-install-to-harddisk/24700#24700)