# My screen is disabled for a long time after I click "Install to harddisk"

Tags: 10.10, installation, ubuntu-netbook

Yes my laptop lcd screen is disabled and maybe black after I click the install to hard disk option on a USB stick.

This worked well on another laptop pc, but not on this.

- I tried to set `acpi=off`
- I reset the bios settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable "apic" as well as acpi.

When editing the boot options, use both `acpi=off` *and* `noapic`.

You can edit the boot options by pressing F6 on the boot screen (hit Escape when the little picture of a keyboard and a person shows up):

> In addition to displaying a popup menu, the F6 key also activates in-line editing of the boot command. Pressing F6 brings up the popup menu. Pressing ESC, whether selections were made or not, removes the popup window but opens the boot command for editing.
>
> The phrase "Boot Options" is fixed on the left side of the screen. The command scrolls off to the left to leave the right end available for appending. The user may add additional inputs after the "-- ". Allow one space between each additional input.

At the end of the boot options, append both the avove arguments.